# CORS is it safe to allow any ports?

Tags: node.js, security, cors, microservices, vercel

We use vercel/micro and we need to allow multiple origins it makes local development easier and we need to support multiple clients for the future. I was having issues because ports are dynamic for local development. This is what I came up with, and its been working but would this be considered safe? Would it pass a security audit?

```
function isAllowedOrigin({ req, baseUrl }) {
  const allowedOrigins = [new URL(baseUrl.replace(/\/$/g, ""))];
  const origin = new URL(req.headers.origin);
  const foundOrigin = allowedOrigins.find((allowedOrigin) => {
    allowedOrigin.port = origin.port;
    return allowedOrigin.origin === origin.origin;
  });
  return foundOrigin;
}
```

These are the headers

```
 const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization",
  };

  if (isAllowedOrigin({ req, baseUrl })) {
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = req.headers.origin;
  }
```

I could also have a local allowed ports for each micro service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer is from the [Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP) CORS Page](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/CORS_OriginHeaderScrutiny)
A bad server configuration of the CORS headers may expose your users to [Cross site scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

In your example, a malicious user could send a string in origin that lets you crash `new URL('hello') // this throws an error`

To support multiple env you could change the `allowedOrigins` based on the `process.env.NODE_ENV`, assuming you will have one route for dev, one for test and so on: this lets you check dynamically the ports for dev and strict for production.

For a large server farm, it is used the match of the root domain usually.